# How to remove '\' from a string using R?

Tags: r

I am trying to remove `"\"` from the string `"AA0000332\, AA0000331"` and extract `AA0000332` and `AA0000331` separately.

```
> string1 <- "AA0000332\, AA0000331"
Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""AA0000332\,"

> gsub("[^[:alnum:]///' ]", "","AA0000332\, AA0000331")
Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\,"

> substr("AA0000332\, AA0000331", 1, 9)
Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""AA0000332\,"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\\`, you will have to escape the escape character.

```
string1 <- "AA0000332\\, AA0000331"
gsub("[^[:alnum:]///' ]", "","AA0000332\\, AA0000331")
[1] "AA0000332 AA0000331"
substr("AA0000332\\, AA0000331", 1, 9)
[1] "AA0000332"
```

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: @RanonKahn Just like that, the way I've written it. I've once seen an explanation. For what I've understood, the first escape character allows the `R` parser to pass the second to the regex parser. Others more knowledgeable than me feel free to pop in and explain better or correct me.

Comment: I am getting this kind of strings in multiple columns in a large data frame. I am wondering how to add another escape character to the string using a R code.

Comment: @RanonKahn In that case you should edit your question and give us an example dataset. Can you use `dput(head(df, 20))` and post the output of this command?

Comment: The problem is I am pulling some data from JIRA search and some of the data are in "AA0000332\, AA0000331" and I am neither able to save the query result nor process the data any further.That is the reason I am not able to present the data structure in the forum using dput.

Comment: @RanonKahn Can't you put a small file on dropbox or some other place like that?

Answer (score 2):

If all your strings contains letters and numbers then you can try

```
library(stringr)
string1 <- "AA0000332\\, AA0000331"
unlist(str_extract_all(string1, "([A-Za-z0-9]+)"))
```

which results in

```
[1] "AA0000332" "AA0000331"
```